# Confused About Laravel Providers and Contracts

Tags: laravel-5

Hi I am new to Laravel and I am try to grasp the concept of creating and using service providers and contracts in my development. I was reading this article

[How to Create a Service Provider in Laravel 5.1](https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/how-to-create-a-service-provider-in-laravel-5-1/)

It talked about how they are both created and used but I still have a hard time grasping the idea of it.

The article mention this hopefully someone can discuss this more indepth

> So why bother making a contract? Well, one of the amazing features in Laravel is that you can type hint the contract, and the service provider will return an instance of whatever concrete class you have bound to it.

They also mention this

> Ok, now we need to create the service provider, which will bind the contract and the concrete class.

What is this binding? how does it work from top to bottom? Whats the point of doing a bind?

Is dependency injection only for services?

Comment: Just to add to the other more elaborate answers - think of it this way: If you have an application that has different billing methods (say Stripe and PayPal) - then creating an interface would definitely be a good idea. If, in the future, you add a third one - you can this way make sure that you can switch back and forth between all different methods in your application, whilst ensuring they all still operate the same, and don't break anything else. Jeff explained it very well in Laracasts "Service Providers Decoded".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually contarcts are interfaces and an interface basically forces a developer to implement some methods if a developer uses that interface like:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    public function SomeMethod();
}

class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {

    public function SomeMethod()
    {
        // Code ... 
    }
}
```

This is a core feature of [PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) and this way one can ensure that, if a class is type of some interface then that concrete class have definitely implemented the required methods declared in that interface. So, in this the class `SomeClass` is using (implements) the `SomeInterface` so according the rule the class must implement the methods that was declared in the `SomeInterface` interface otherwise `PHP` will throw error. Probably not clear enough but anyways, read the `PHP` documentation (link given above).

So, an interface is used only to declare the method headers/signatures but not for implementating the methods and an interface is not instantiatable using `new SomeInterface()`.

On the other hand, the class that implements the interface is bound to that interface for implementing the interface so it must implements the methods declared in the interface and hence any class that implements an interface can be considered the type of that interface. For example, the `SomeClass` implemented the `SomeInterface` interface so the following is true:

```
$instance = new SomeClass;
echo $instance instanceof SomeInterface; // 1 as true

if($instance instanceof SomeInterface) {
    echo 'SomeClass is the type of SomeInterface';
}
```

So, as you might know that you can typehint an object using the class as the type, for example:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(SomeClass $SomeClassInstance)
    {
        $this->$someClass = $SomeClassInstance;

    }
}
```

In this case, the `Laravel` framework is able to inject the dependency ('SomeClass') automatically when it initializes the `UserController` class and this happens behind the scene with the help of `Laravel ServiceContainer` which in turn uses [PHP Reflection Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) to read the type and makes an instance and inject it on the fly.

Now, when you use a concrete class, for example `SomeClass` here, as a dependency then it's possible for the container class to automatically inject the dependency without any user interaction because it can read (reverse engineering) the constructor method of the `UserController` class and can determine the type of that dependency and easily can inject the dpendency but if you use an interface to type hint then the Laravel framework reads the type as usual and tries to make an instance of that type and here it fails. Why, because an interface is not instatiatable and it needs some information to make the `UserController` instance here. So, let's write the previous example using the `SomeInterfrace` as the dependency:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(SomeInterface $SomeClassInstance)
    {
        $this->$someClass = $SomeClassInstance;

    }
}
```

Now, it's obvious that, `Laravel` will fail to make an instance of `UserController` class because it has a dependency which is an interface and it can't make an intance of an interface so at this situation, you need to use a service provider class to bind a class with the interface or in other words, you'll need to tell the `Laravel` framework which class it should inject when it sees that interface and it's a simple maping of `interface vs class` but nothing else. To do this, using a service provider is a good choice because the framework runs every serviceproviders available and runs the `register` and `boot` method during the boot up process of the framework. This is a typical example of a service provider:

```
class UserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(SomeINterface::class, SomeClass::class);
    }
}
```

So, now the `Service Container` will be able to inject the dependency by reading the mapping `key => value` from the container itself. It'll know that, it should inject the `SomeClass` class when it sees the `SomeInterface` interface. That's it.

Well, I've oitted the `use` and comments but hope you've got the idea. Read the documentations (source code as well) and by the time you'll master it.

Answer (score 1):

**Creating the Interface**

```
interface CarInterface {
    public function start();
    public function gas();
    public function brake();
}
```

This tells our code that we can have any type of car we want, as long as it implements a start() gas() and brake() method. This is the API or contract of the interface.

**Create a Class that Implements the Interface**

This is also quite easy. All we have to do is create a class as we normally would, but we need to make sure we add the implements keyword to our definition:

```
class Subaru implements CarInterface {
    public function start() {
        echo 'Starts great';
    }
    public function gas()  {
        echo 'Hit the gas and let the all wheel drive grip those back roads!';
    }
    public function brake() {
        echo 'Wow these Brembo brakes are powerful';
    }
}
```

**Start Using Your Interface!**

we set up our CarInterace and we have a class that implements it, we’re future proofing our application and making sure we have testability baked in as well since we can so easily swap instances in and out of our app. Let’s test this puppy out:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    dd(App::make('CarInterface'));  
});
```

Whoops, there was an error! Illuminate Container BindingResolutionException Target [CarInterface] is not instantiable. Ok, we made a boo boo. It looks like we can’t directly instantiate an interface. Oh yes! We need to bind it first!

**Bind Your Interface**

We can easily bind our interface to the app like by adding

```
App::bind('CarInterface', 'Subaru');


    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        $car = App::make('CarInterface');  
        $car->start();
        $car->gas();
        $car->brake();
    });
    //  Starts great
    //  Hit the gas and let the all wheel drive grip those back roads!
    //  Wow these Brembo brakes are powerful
```

More in this [article](http://vegibit.com/what-is-a-laravel-interface/)

and i think This book can be a great resource for you

TAYLOR OTWELL - LARAVEL, FROM APPRENTICE TO ARTISAN

In short way, the binding will link(maybe this is not the right term but i hope you get what i mean) your interface to the concrete class,

Answer (score 0):

I find some of the Laravel terminology confusing.  To me, service provider is not really an intuitive description of what it does.

Also, the whole idea of contracts seems almost pointless for smaller projects done by just one or two people which is quite common.  Laravel assumes everything is going to be huge and complicated and developed by multiple people.

I get the philosophy behind OOP but at some point trying to separate things out and bending over backwards to not duplicate anything goes too far and makes the code more difficult to follow.

One other area where laravel kind of bugs me is this idea that it wants coders to think of themselves as artists.  So they use these fancy names like eloquent and illuminate and artisan. Those are kind of intimidating words to new developers. It goes against the idea of trying to simplify things.  If they really want to prioritize simplification over thinking of themselves as web artists then maybe start with the terminology.

It's not art like painting.  If you get a spot of paint somewhere it does not ruin the painting.  If you forget a semicolon in your code the whole thing crashes. If you want to call it art then call it art for robots because you have to be robotic and precise in your syntax.